# Did an MH370 passenger text a claim of hijacking?

Tags: aviation, mh370

A recent spreading rumour about the missing [Malaysian Airlines Flight 370](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370) (MH370) is that a passenger sent a message claiming to be hijacked:

> "I have been held hostage by unknown military personal after my flight was hijacked (blindfolded). I work for IBM and I have managed to hide my cellphone in my ass during the hijack. I have been separated from the rest of the passengers and I am in a cell. My name is Philip Wood. I think I have been drugged as well and cannot think clearly."

[Source](http://intellihub.com/freelance-journalist-hijacked-flight-370-passenger-sent-photo-hidden-iphone-tracing-back-secret-u-s-military-base-diego-garcia/)

Is the rumour true - i.e. that such a message was sent from a passenger after the plane went missing?

Comment: Not a definitive proof either way, but something to consider: http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/599910-diego-garcia-source-for-alleged-philip-wood-photo-revealed-to-be-4chan-likely-hoax/

Comment: Also, it has been pointed out that cell service is usually blocked at bases like Diego Garcia, so the claim that he sent a photo from his iPhone is not very plausible.

Comment: Of course, if you want to go down the rabbit hole, you could say that "they" meant to let his photo get out for some unlikely reason unbeknownst to us.

Answer (score 14):

The purported message wasn't sent to the passenger's family, the press or authorities. Instead, its source has been [traced back](http://www.theepochtimes.com/n3/599910-diego-garcia-source-for-alleged-philip-wood-photo-revealed-to-be-4chan-likely-hoax/) as an [anonymous message](http://archive.4plebs.org/pol/thread/27834494/#27834494) to, of all places, a [4chan forum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4chan).

As their Wikipedia page describes, 4chan is the source of a number of hoaxes; it is not a reputable source.

There is no credible evidence to suggest that the message is anything other than a hoax in poor taste, that has been swallowed by some irrational conspiracy theorists.